# ¿Cómo puedo validar si el valor de una celda de un DataGridView es Null?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de validar el contenido de una celda dentro de un DataGridView cuando se dispara el evento CellValidated y he visto diferentes formas de tratar el problema, pero no logro conseguir evitar el error de valor Null a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación.

El error que obtengo es `NullReferenceException was Unhandled` y que la referencia no esta establecida como instancia de un objeto. Este error sucede cuando dejo la celda en blanco para pasar a otra celda, en el `If` es cuando se cae. Cabe resaltar que estoy usando el `Grid` para un ingreso directo.

Lo que estoy pensando incluir es un `try..catch` para lograr hacer un bypass al problema, pero creo que esa no es la mejor opción.

El código del evento que estoy usando es el que sigue:

```
private void dgvProductosPropios_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvProductosPropios.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "_marcaCodigo")
    {
        if (dgvProductosPropios.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == String.Empty) 
            cMarca = dgvProductosPropios.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        else
            cMarca = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta validando primero la celda:

```
private void dgvProductosPropios_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
          if (!CeldaEsNull(dgvProductosPropios.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]))
           {
            if (dgvProductosPropios.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "_marcaCodigo")
            {
                if (dgvProductosPropios.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == String.Empty) 
                    cMarca = dgvProductosPropios.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                else
                    cMarca = "";
            }
           }
        }

private bool CeldaEsNull(DataGridViewCell celda)
{
 return celda.Value == null || celda.Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(celda.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Hola Tuco, hice la prueba con el cambio que recomiendas y el problema sigue sucediendo, la ruta esta llegando al tercer IF y se detiene con el error antes mecionado, al parecer la validación de NULL es mas compleja de lo que parece. Voy a seguir haciendo pruebas.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, intenta de nuevo

Comment: Excelente Tuco, ahora si funciona, solo el 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace' necesita la letra [S] en mayusculas y falta el [;] al final de la linea. Por lo demás todo perfecto. Voy a hacer más pruebas. Muchas gracias.